# EF Core One to Many adding new object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.1

I have tried many ways but I am still hitting different kinds of errors for each solution. I have tried to stop tracking, tried adding `challenge` itself, updating `competition` but all of them doesn't seem to work.

I basically have 1 competition to many challenges, and in this scenario, 1 `competition` and 1 `challenge` is already present, and I am adding another `challenge` which has a Foreign Key linking with the `competition`. I understand that I have asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972251/asp-net-ef-core-inserting-into-multiple-tables-with-foreign-key) before, but that was for bulk creation of 1 competition to many categories. I am thinking this is more like an update operation, which doesn't seem to be working. Appreciate your help a lot! :)

> InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Challenge'
>   cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for
>   {'ID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities,
>   ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is
>   attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.

`Competition` Model Class:

```
public class Competition
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CompetitionCategory> CompetitionCategories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Challenge> Challenges { get; set; }
}
```

`Challenge` Model Class:

```
public class Challenge
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompetitionID")]
    public int CompetitionID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Competition Category")]
    [ForeignKey("CompetitionCategoryID")]
    public int CompetitionCategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,XXX,CompetitionID,CompetitionCategoryID")] Challenge challenge)
{
    var competition = await _context.Competitions
    .Include(c => c.CompetitionCategories)
    .Include(c1 => c1.Challenges)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == challenge.CompetitionID);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //_context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        competition.Challenges.Add(challenge);

        _context.Update(competition);
        _context.Entry(competition).State = EntityState.Detached;
        _context.Entry(competition.Challenges).State = EntityState.Detached;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //_context.Add(challenge);
        //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Challenges", new { id = challenge.CompetitionID });
    }

     return View();
 }
```

Update: I have actually tried to just add `challenge` itself but it also throws up another error. Really quite at a lost of what to do.

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in
>   table 'Challenges' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__122_0(Task
>   result)
>
> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See
>   the inner exception for details.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Update 2: Removing the ID from the binding works as there was some unknown ID value being passed in and being tracked. Ivan's answer on adding a new object with Foreign Key is correct.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("XXX,CompetitionID,CompetitionCategoryID")] Challenge challenge)
{
    //Codes here
    _context.Add(challenge);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Please provide the `Challenge` class.

Comment: Edited with Competition and Challenge class. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with disconnected entities is not easy and requires different techniques depending of the presense/absense of navigation / innverse navigation and FK properties in the entity model.

Your `Challenge` class has explicit FK properties and no navigation properties. Adding new object like this is the simplest operation - just call `DbContext.Add` or `DbSet.Add`:

```
_context.Add(challenge);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

However, the exception you are getting makes me think that the `Challenge` object received by the `Create` method has the PK property `Id` populated with a value of an existing `Challenge`. If you really want to add new `Challenge` and `Id` is auto-generated, exclude `Id` from the binding or make sure it is set to `0` (zero) before calling `Add`.

For more info, see [Disconnected Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities) and related links in the EF Core documentation.

Comment: Oh my yes you are right. Seems like the Id of challenge is really populated with some value, although I did not set it, which is kind of weird. And yep your solution worked, but I had to remove the ID from the binding as I assume it was causing issues there

Comment: I have updated my answer to specify the binding Id was the issue and the codes you shared for adding works :)